# Shorthand way of assigning type to primitive literal

Tags: c++, types, overloading, literals

What are the ways of assigning a type to a literal primitive without a cast?
I know 0.0 becomes a double and 0.0f becomes float. Are there other ways to typecast a literal?

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve? I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I don't want to do 'static_cast< uint32_t >( 0 )' every time. I just can't seem to get google to tell me how to do things like the 0.0f shorthand

Comment: Can you reword your question to ask that? I don't know what the union has to do with anything.

Comment: `0u` is `unsigned`, so it will hopefully call the `uint32_t` constructor.

Comment: Btw, you can write `0.0f` as `0.f`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of [suffixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal) that you can add to integer literals to get the types you want:

```
1    // int
2u   // unsigned int
3ll  // long long int
4ull // unsigned long long int
```

Similarly, for [floating literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), no suffix gives you `double`, `f` gives you `float`, and `l` gives you `long double`.

There is no prepackaged literal suffix for types smaller than `int`. But you can write your own, e.g.:

```
inline uint16_t operator ""_u16(uint64_t value) {
    return static_cast<uint16_t>(value);
}

5_u16 // uint16_t
```

---

Except VC apparently provides literal suffixes for all the types - like `10i16` gives you an `int16_t`.